# logical opertation !A && !B vs !(A||B)

Tags: logical-operators

I often see the following statement in embedded software

```
!A && !B
```

rather than

```
! (A || B)
```

Although both give the same truth table value.

I often use the http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ to 
check complex logical operations.

Is there logical reason to it? Is there any general rule/best practice/conventions in using logical statements in regards to time critical applications?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it also works for `||` if `A` is `true`. At least in C and C++

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Why do you need compute `B` in `(A || B)` if `A` is already `true`?

Comment: @A. Albershteyn: Sorry, need more coffee, you are right

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I tend to accept the approach of asking/considering how cheap or heavy the operation is.